# How to export across collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I would like to export information across collection. For example, I have 2 collection **User** and **Orders**. User contains login info(username) and orders contains the orderID. So when a customer purchases something, the orderID will be generated in the **Orders** collection and their userID(not the same as username) will be recorded in the order. So I have to reference the userID to find the username within **User** collection.

I would like to export the orderID alongside the username. Is that possible? As it currently stands, mongodb compass has the export button only when you've selected the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example your user collection is like this
users collection

```
[{
_id:123,
username:example,
}]
```

orders collection

```
[{
_id:234
userId : ObjectId('123')
orderPrice : 300
}]
```

so you could get order in user object like this with $lookup

```
db.orders.aggregate([
{
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'users', // users collection 
            'localField': 'userId', 
            'foreignField': '_id', 
            'as': 'order'
        }
])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **lookup** operator to get user's name alongside orderID.
[MongoDB Official Documentation for lookup operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)